# 2 backgrounds on body: how to set the height for the backgrounds

Tags: css, background

I've got this code:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(images/header.png), url(images/footer.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
    background-height: 50px , 400px; /* ?? */
    background-position: 0% 0%, 0% 100%;

}
```

Can I give the footer.png a height that will repeat in that specific height?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "repeat in that specific height"?

Comment: I mean that the second image has a height of 200 px or something, but I need to repeat that image, but when I put repeat, the image will repeat over the whole body which I dont need:
I need that the background repeats at x 100% then 400 px up or something, I hope im clear now :)

Comment: Better you create the separate div and set the background image and set height and width of that div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `background-size`:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(images/header.png), url(images/footer.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
    background-size: auto, auto 500px; // here give to background images height
    background-position: 0% 0%, 0% 100%;


}
```

More info about `background-size` [is here](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/).

Comment: This is the css3 properties ie+9

Comment: multiple backgrounds only supports IE9+

Comment: Hi Rohit, please consider leaving out the "....." in your answer as this creates a lot of noise in the post that others have to clean up. Also, it looks like there was a [possible bug caused by this that made it so you had to edit your post a second time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156544/155826). One way to avoid that is to stop adding in the dots. ;)  Good luck!

Comment: You're welcome @RohitAzad. Also, it looks like the "Hi" in your message is what's causing your problem too. The link I posted has more details about why that keeps happening to you. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create the separate div and specify that.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(images/header.png), ;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-height: 50px , 400px; 
    background-position: 0% 0%, 0% 100%;
    div {
        background-image: url(images/footer.png);
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-height: 50px , 400px;
    }
}
```